# How to access App_Code/file.cs from a aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-code

I have the following file: `App_code/utility.cs`. This file needs to be accessed via a `aspx` file.  In my aspx file I have the following `<%@ Import Namespace ="../App_Code/Utility.cs" %>`. When I try to build it I get the following error: `Identifier expected`. How do I access App_code/file.cs from a aspx file?

a small sample of the Utility.cs file:

```
public class Utility
 {
  public static string EncryptString(string fieldValue, string IV = "")
   {
      //code in here

    }
 }
```

this is what the start of the aspx file look like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="file.aspx.cs" Inherits="file" EnableEventValidation="false" EnableViewState="true" %>

<%@ Import Namespace ="../App_Code/Utility.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: A filename or file path isn't a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not use `namespace` then direct call it on aspx page - like that.

```
<%=Utility.EncryptString("theEncodedString") %>
```

if you have namespace eg, if you have

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
  public class Utility
  {
     public static string EncryptString(string fieldValue, string IV = "")
     {
        //code in here
     }
   }
}
```

then you can declare it on the page

```
<%@ Import Namespace ="myNameSpace" %>
```

or direct use it to locate you class as

```
<%=myNameSpace.Utility.EncryptString("theEncodedString") %>
```

The files on App_Code compile as a dll library - you then use their class by including their namespace (and not by reference the file) - for asp.net the file is not exist, the compiled version of it as a dll exist.

Comment: I tried this method and got the following error: `'AjaxControlToolkit.Utility' does not contain a definition for 'EncryptString'`

Comment: @Suji its because its mess up with ToolKit Utility - I suggest to add a name space - see my edited answer, and add a namespace, to separate you class